# Increment value at runtime while running loop in cURL

Tags: scripting, variable, curl

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do curl -s --user 'api:key- MY_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox/messages \
    -F from='test1@gmail.com' \
    -F to='test@site.com'  \
    -F subject='Test Subject' \
    -F text='Hey'; done
```

Here I'm able to run 5 requests using for loop, but I want to increase the value of From email by 1 on each request, eg: *test1@gmail.com*, *test2@gmail.com*, any suggestion how I can do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `$i` instead of `1` and keep the text in double quotes instead of single quotes for that option:

```bsh
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do curl -s --user 'api:key- MY_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox/messages \
    -F from="test$i@gmail.com" \
    -F to='test@site.com'  \
    -F subject='Test Subject' \
    -F text='Hey'; done
```

`$i` is the value of the variable `i`, which you are incrementing from 1 to 5 in the loop.

Comment: Happens rarely :) Usually somebody always beats me to it.

Comment: @Sam Since you seem to be new, you might want to consider accepting an answer if it worked for you. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hey, yeah i'm new here, and just accepted, thanks :)